# Modifying Tricky Outer SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I am interested in modifying an outer query to broaden query results in a very specific way.

My inner query creates a table. The outer query creates conditions that removes records from the table. What I want the outer query to remove are records where the word "not" is contained in the same sentence as the phrases that are in both queries ("%postterm%", "%post__term%", "after__term%", etc...)

So far, the outer query only removes records where "not" ends two characters before the phrase.

"not" can come either before or after this phrase. The condition I need is whether "not" is included with this phrase between periods.

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers.

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 10000 *
    FROM MyTable N
    WHERE

  (N.[Subject] like '%postterm%')
  OR
  (N.[Content] like '%postterm%')
  ORpos
  (N.[Subject] like '%post_term%')
  OR
  (N.[Content] like '%post_term%')
  Or
  (N.[Subject] like '%post__term%')
  OR
  (N.[Content] like '%post__term%')
  OR
  (N.[Subject] like '%afterterm%')
  OR
  (N.[Content] like '%afterterm%')
  OR
  (N.[Subject] like '%after_term%')
  OR
  (N.[Content] like '%after_term%')
  Or
  (N.[Subject] like '%after__term%')
  OR
  (N.[Content] like '%after__term%')

) sub

WHERE

  (sub.[Subject] not like '%not_postterm%'

    )
      OR

  (sub.[Content] not like '%not_postterm%')
  OR
  (sub.[Subject] not like '%not_post_term%')
  OR
  (sub.[Content] not like '%not_post_term%')
  Or
  (sub.[Subject] not like '%not_post__term%')
  OR
  (sub.[Content] not like '%not_post__term%')
  OR
  (sub.[Subject] not like '%not_afterterm%')
  OR
  (sub.[Content] not like '%not_afterterm%')
  OR
  (sub.[Subject] not like '%not_after_term%')
  OR
  (sub.[Content] not like '%not_after_term%')
  Or
  (sub.[Subject] not like '%not_after__term%')
  OR
  (sub.[Content] not like '%not_after__term%')
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're up to but using a bunch of logical ORs operating on  negative tests, 'not like', will usually end up giving you all the rows in the table because every row will match at least one of the 'not like's

Comment: At the very least, all of the `OR`s in your `WHERE` clause should be `AND`s instead.

Comment: I see! Just changed the outer query from ORs to ANDs.

Comment: Please give some sample data. Some data that should be picked and data that shouldn't be picked.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done in a much cleverer query. Needs to be Sql Server 2012 or later for the String_Split function, otherwise look uphow to create your own function.

```
-- Set up the content
declare @T table(ID int, Content varchar(1000))
insert @t values (1, 'Hello. This is not Post Term. Another sentence')
insert @t values (2, 'Another. This is Post Term. Another sentence 2')

-- Define the search terms
declare @check table(Term varchar(100))
insert @check values ('%postterm%'),('%post_term%'),('%post__term%'),('%afterterm%'),('%after_term%'),('%after__term%')

-- This query shows you how how it works
SELECT ID, Content, SPL.value, Term, 
    case when value like '% NOT %' then 1 else 0 end as HasNot
FROM @T  AS PP
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Content,'.') AS SPL
left join @check on SPL.Value like term

-- Final result
; with results as (
    SELECT ID, Content, SPL.value, Term, 
        case when value like '% NOT %' then 1 else 0 end as HasNot
    FROM @T  AS PP
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Content,'.') AS SPL
    left join @check on SPL.Value like term
)
select distinct ID,Content 
from results 
where term is not null and HasNot=1
```